# Is the region of interest a good design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, opencv, language-agnostic

The image processing library OpenCV has a concept called a RegionOfInterest that causes most functions to only operate on that region. The region can be set, moved, unset, etc.

I'm working on a similar application data, and I'm considering using a similar pattern, selecting a region and having analysis and processing occur within that region.

Is the region of interest a recommended design pattern? I understand that it improves performance in OpenCV, which is an application that needs high performance. My application would benefit from high performance, but its not as important as it would be in OpenCV.

What alternatives are there? I'm considering creating a Region object that solves the same problem but, for example, multiple regions can be created from the same set of data. Does this method have any serious disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

The Region of Interest is really linked to the nature of the object you are treating: images, which are continuous 2D (or higher dimensional) lattices or regularly sample point (pixels). It is very useful in image processing to work only on some part of the image, i.e. the region of interest: it can speed up a process, or even save some memory if only the ROI is kept. On big advantage in ROI, is that they are bound to simple geometrical shapes such as rectangles, so it is very easy to handle.

If your data has not such a structure as images, you can always use a proper design pattern such as [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Using composite patterns, you can set up (sub)groups of data, and perform operations on a group which is applied to each single element in the group.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sound like a variant of Observer. The functions "observe" only a particular part of the state of the system, and are only activated with regards to that.

So my answer is yes :)

Answer (score 0):

To me, "region of interest" corresponds to a singleton of what you call a "Region" object. So your decision boils down to deciding whether you want/need/can afford one or many "Region" objects.

Is thread-safety or reentrancy an issue?

Answer (score 0):

the region of interest is probably not a *design* pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern. *design* patterns (plus or minus a few) are what is in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29. there are lots of *other* types of patterns. see http://hillside.net/patterns/

Answer (score 0):

To *identify* a ROI it's key to perform actual algorithms we are interested.

I worked on barcode recognition, and given the availability of open source libraries actually solving the decode phase, I experienced the difficulty to perform the task *without* a ROI.

Algorithms are designed to work well on some *specific* kind if data, and I would say that ROI identification is almost *essential* in practical image processing.